Why is $\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)\approx \sum_i \sigma_i^{2p}$ for this random matrix?
I have a matrix $A$ where the following appears to hold for $p\ge1$ and singular values $\sigma_i$
$$\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)\approx \sum_i \sigma_i^{2p}$$
This approximation is very good when $A$ is a product of random projections and $d=100$:

This holds for non-integer $p$, if we discard the imaginary part of the trace

Why?
d = 100;
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
isotropic = Normalize /@ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
A = Dot @@ Table[ii - {v}\[Transpose] . {v}, {v, isotropic}];

maxP = 10;
powers = NestList[A . # &, A, maxP - 1];

plot1 = ListPlot[Tr /@ powers, Filling -> Axis, PlotRange -> All];
plot2 = Plot[Total[SingularValueList[A]^(2 p)], {p, 1, maxP}, 
   PlotRange -> All];
Show[plot2, plot1, AxesLabel -> {"p"}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]


Related question on math.SE
Notebook


Just two opposite cases: 1) $A=U\prod_i(E_iV)U^{T}$ where $(E_i){p,q}=(1-\delta{p,i})\delta_{p,q}, U={v_1, v_2, ..,v_d}, V=UU^{T}$. If $U \in O(d)$, all the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero. 2) If all $v_i$ are same, then $AA^{T}=A$. Both cases support the result.

Is your $p$ integer? Otherwise, I do not understand what does $A^p$ mean.

@FedorPetrov this relation appears to also hold for non-integer $p$ if we define $\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)=\sum_i \lambda_i^p$ where ${\lambda_i}$ are eigenvalues of $A$

Are all eigenvalues real?

@FedorPetrov correction, the relation appears to hold for non-integer $p$ only if we discard the imaginary part, ie define $\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)=\sum_i \mathcal{R}(\lambda_i^p)$

Re: "discarding the imaginary part": because $A$ is real, the eigenvalues appear in complex conjugate pairs $\lambda_i$ and $\bar{\lambda}_i$, so the imaginary part will not contribute to $\operatorname{Tr}(A^p)$ if you define $(\bar{z})^p=\overline{(z^p)}$.

But how do you define $r^p$ for not real $r$?

Alternating projections
The von-Neumann-Halperin theorem, and the symmetric generalization of it (see Accelerating the Convergence of the Method of Alternating Projections, theorems 2.6 and 2.7), states that both $A^p$ and $(AA^\top)^p$ converge in the limit of integer $p\rightarrow\infty$ to the projector onto the intersection of the subspaces of the individual projections in $A$. This justifies the result in the OP in the large-$p$ limit, but does not explain why it holds so accurately for small $p$.
The isotropic distribution of the unit projection vectors plays a key role here. Indeed, if I replace the "NormalDistribution" by a "UniformDistribution", so that the vectors are normalized but not isotropic, the agreement between $\operatorname{Tr}A^p$ and $\operatorname{Tr}\,(AA^\top)^p$ no longer holds.
Gaussian approximation
I note that for large $d$ it does not matter if we omit the normalization to unit length of the isotropically distributed vectors $v_i$, and instead draw the $d$ elements of $v_i$ independently from a Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance $1/d$. Indeed, in that case the agreement between $\operatorname{Tr}A^p$ and $\operatorname{Tr}\,(AA^\top)^p$ continues to hold, see plot (for $d=100$).

Recursion relations
It is helpful to distinguish the dimensionality $d$ of the vectors from the number $n$ of projectors in $A$, and define
$$A_n=(I-v_nv_n^\top)(I-v_{n-1}v_{n-1}^\top)\cdots (I-v_{1}v_{1}^\top).$$
I seek the average $S_p(n)=\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Tr}A_n^p]$. I take random Gaussian vectors $v_i$, with elements that have mean zero and variance $1/d$. The Gaussian averages follow from Wick contractions. To leading order in $1/d$ this gives a set of nested recursion relations of the form

\begin{align}
&S_0(n)=d,\\
&S_1(n)=(1-1/d)S_1(n-1),\\
&S_2(n) = (1-2/d) S_2(n-1) + (1/d^2) S_1(n-1)^2 +{\cal O}(1/d),\\
&S_3(n) = (1-3/d) S_3(n-1) - (1/d^3) S_1(n-1)^3 + (3/d^2) S_1(n-1) S_2(n-1)+{\cal O}(1/d),\\
&S_4(n) = (1-4/d) S_4(n-1) + (1/d^4) S_1(n-1)^4 - (4/d^3) S_1(n-1)^2 S_2(n-1)+ (2/d^2)S_2(n-1)^2 + (4/d^2)S_1(n-1)S_3(n-1)+{\cal O}(1/d),\\
&S_5(n) = (1-5/d) S_5(n-1) - (1/d^5) S_1(n-1)^5 + (5/d^4) S_1(n-1)^3 S_2(n-1) - (5/d^3)S_1(n-1)S_2(n-1)^2 - (5/d^3)S_1(n-1)^2S_3(n-1) + (5/d^2)S_2(n-1)S_3(n-1) + (5/d^2)S_1(n-1)S_4(n-1) +{\cal O}(1/d),
\end{align}

and so on for larger $p$. (The order $1/d$ correction takes into account that $S_p(n)$ itself is of order $d$.) From the solutions to these recursion relations I conjecture that
$$\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{d}S_p(d)=\frac{p^p}{p!e^p}.\tag{*}$$
This agrees nicely with the numerics, see the plot, where I show $\operatorname{Tr}A^p$ for $d=n=100$ as a function of $p$ (data points, for a particular realization of the random projectors), and the Gaussian large-$d$ approximation $\operatorname{Tr}A^p\simeq\frac{dp^p}{p!e^p}$ (red line). For large $p$ the moments decay as $d/\sqrt{2\pi p}$. The corresponding probability density function is considered here.

I checked equation (*) for small $p$, I do not have a proof that it holds for all $p$, but fortunately I do not need that for the central question in the OP, to which I can now finally turn.
Correspondence of $A^p$ and $(AA^\top)^p$
Consider the two averages $S_p(n)=\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Tr}A_n^p]$ and $Q_p(n)=\mathbb{E}[\operatorname{Tr}(A_nA_n^\top)^p]$. We wish to show that they satisfy, for each $p$, the same recursion relations in $n$ in the large-$d$, Gaussian, approximation, so the two averages are the same for all $n,p$.
This is indeed the case: Define $P=I-v_nv_n^\top$ and substitute $A_n=PA_{n-1}$:
$$\operatorname{Tr}A_n^p = \operatorname{Tr}(PA_{n-1})^p\tag{1}.$$
Similarly, with $B_n\equiv A_nA_n^\top$, one has
$$\operatorname{Tr}B_n^p = \operatorname{Tr}(PB_{n-1} P)^p=\operatorname{Tr}(PB_{n-1})^p,\tag{2}$$
since $P^2=P$. If I now perform the Gaussian average over $v_n$, retaining the leading order terms in $1/d$, equation (1) relates $\operatorname{Tr}A_n^p$ to $\operatorname{Tr}A_{n-1}^q$ with $q\leq p$, in the very same way that equation (2) relates $\operatorname{Tr}B_n^p$ to $\operatorname{Tr}B_{n-1}^q$ with $q\leq p$.

To be specific, for $X=S$ or $X=Q$ one has
\begin{align}
&X_0(n)=d,\\
&X_1(n)=(1-1/d)X_1(n-1),\\
&X_2(n) = (1-2/d) X_2(n-1) + (1/d^2) X_1(n-1)^2 +{\cal O}(1/d),\\
&X_3(n) = (1-3/d) X_3(n-1) - (1/d^3) X_1(n-1)^3 + (3/d^2) X_1(n-1) X_2(n-1)+{\cal O}(1/d),
\end{align}
and so on. Up to terms of order $1/d$, the recursion relations are the same for $S_p(n)$ and $Q_p(n)$. The initial condition is also the same, $S_p(0)=Q_p(0)=d$. The solutions are therefore identical in the large-$d$ approximation, in particular, $$\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty} d^{-1}S_p(d)=\lim_{d\rightarrow\infty} d^{-1}Q_p(d).$$ 
The large-$d$ approximation is crucial to ensure that the recursion relations for $S_p(n)$ and $Q_p(n)$ close on themselves. Higher order terms in $1/d$ contain additional traces that are not of the form $\operatorname{Tr}A_n^p$, $\operatorname{Tr}(A_nA_n^\top)^p$ and which appear differently for $S_p(n)$ and $Q_p(n)$.


BTW, equality in $p=1$ case can be shown to hold in expectation using basic algebra here

@YaroslavBulatov I tried to extend the analysis and get $p = 1$ holds in probability (scaled variance vanishes) and $p = 2$ holds in expectation: here

I think I'm done. I wish to acknowledge the key insight I obtained from Xiangxiang Xu 's answer.
